# L = { <M> : TM does not accept any thing }

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, computation, tableofcontents

```
L = { <M> : TM does not accept any thing }
```

We can feed strings to TM one  by one as long as TM will accept. If there are no such strings , then this process will go infinite time so we can not decide. Hence **Recursive Enumerable**.

```
P = { <M> : TM accept atleast one string }
```

We can say it is Semi decidable. We can feed strings to TM one by one as long as it will accept at least one string. But this process can go infinite time and no guarantee that TM will halt , hence **Recursive Enumerable.**
If above both logics are correct then how can L and P ( both are complement to each other) Recursive Enumerable at the same time.

```
If L and P are complement to each other and both are Recursive Enumerable then L must be Recursive.
```

where am I wrong ??

Comment: Note: What if first string fed to `P` will cause infinite loop? You have to be more careful when feeding strings to `P`. Similar thing goes for `L`.

Comment: @Zereges Yes , 1st string can go in infinite loop that's why it is RE. But how can both complemented language are RE ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: L isn't RE.

For it to be RE, you have to be able to determine that a string/TM IS in the language in finite time.  Your technique for determining that does not satisfy this requirement; it allows you determine that a string/TM is NOT in the language in finite time (by finding an input the TM will accept), but because a TM is not required to stop on a string that won't be accepted, it may never stop for ANY unaccepted string.  Thus, it is co-RE, which is why its compliment is RE ("co"is short for "complementary").

Note that it IS possible for a language and its complement to both be RE: that intersection would be a decidable language.

Comment: I got my mistake. Thank you !  But can you please explain your last statement. How can language and its complement be RE ??

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in the fact that `L` is semi decidable.

`P` is semi decidable, if we carefully feed strings to it. See following pseudo-code

```
i <- 0;
while (true) {
    foreach x in combanitaions of alphabet, such that |x| <= i {           (\Sigma^*)
        if (Simulate M for up to i steps == Accept) {
            Accept;
        }
    }
    ++i
}
```

If `M` accepts at least one string, we will find it someday, thus `P` (actually `NONEMPTY`) is semi-deducible.

`NONEMPTY` isn't deducible, which can be seen from Universal Language (`Lu`) being reducible to `NONEMPTY`

```
Lu = { <M,x> | x ∊ L(M) }
```

And `Lu <= NONEMPTY` holds (can add proof later). And since `Lu` isn't deducible, `NONEMPTY` can't be deducible either.

Thus, by Post's theorem, complement of `NONEMTPY` (your `L`), can't be even semi deducible.